# File mode error when trying to write using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have problem with file handling. The function first searching for strings in all files. Then replace them with new values. I don't know how to write new content in same file after all. I thing the problem is file mode but not sure how to deal with that because when I changed mode somewhere else a new error appeared.

```py
 def replace_urls(self):
        find_string_1 = '/blog/'
        find_string_2 = '/contakt/'
        replace_string_1 = 'blog.html'
        replace_string_2 = 'contact.html'

        exclude_dirs = ['media', 'static']

        for (root_path, dirs, files) in os.walk(f'{settings.BASE_DIR}/static/'):
            dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude_dirs]
            for file in files:
                get_file = os.path.join(root_path, file)
                with open(get_file, 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml", from_encoding="utf-8")
                    blog_text = soup.find('a', attrs={'href':find_string_1})
                    contact_text = soup.find('a', attrs={'href':find_string_2})
                    blog_text.attrs['href'] = replace_string_1
                    contact_text.attrs['href'] = replace_string_2
                    f.write(soup.prettify('utf-8'))
```

The code above error:

with open(get_file, 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as f:

ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

**important:**

I want to use this function as django command:

so I call it using `python manage.py command_name`

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.conf import settings
import os
import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help='change urls in each header to static version'


    def replace_urls(self):
        find_string_1 = '/blog/'
        find_string_2 = '/contact/'
        replace_string_1 = 'blog.html'
        replace_string_2 = 'contact.html'

        exclude_dirs = ['media', 'static']

        for (root_path, dirs, files) in os.walk(f'{settings.BASE_DIR}/static/'):
            dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude_dirs]
            for file in files:
                get_file = os.path.join(root_path, file)
                with open(get_file, 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml", from_encoding="utf-8")
                    blog_text = soup.find('a', attrs={'href':find_string_1})
                    contact_text = soup.find('a', attrs={'href':find_string_2})
                    blog_text.attrs['href'] = replace_string_1
                    contact_text.attrs['href'] = replace_string_2
                    f.write(soup.prettify('utf-8'))


    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.replace_urls()
            self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(f'********** Command has been execute without any error **********'))
        except Exception:
            self.stdout.write(self.style.NOTICE(f'********** Command  does not exist ! **********'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 'b' to the open sets the binary mode on.
This mode doesn't support encoding.

You can use the codecs library for this.

Here's my suggestion:

```
import codecs

def replace_urls(self):
        find_string_1 = '/blog/'
        find_string_2 = '/contakt/'
        replace_string_1 = 'blog.html'
        replace_string_2 = 'contact.html'

        exclude_dirs = ['media', 'static']

        for (root_path, dirs, files) in os.walk(f'{settings.BASE_DIR}/static/'):
            dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude_dirs]
            for file in files:
                get_file = os.path.join(root_path, file)
                with codecs.open(get_file, "w", "utf-8") as f:
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml", from_encoding="utf-8")
                    blog_text = soup.find('a', attrs={'href':find_string_1})
                    contact_text = soup.find('a', attrs={'href':find_string_2})
                    blog_text.attrs['href'] = replace_string_1
                    contact_text.attrs['href'] = replace_string_2
                    f.write(soup.prettify('utf-8'))
```

Simple functionality test:

```
import codecs

file = codecs.open("test.txt", "w", "utf-8")
file.write(u'\ufeff')
file.close()
```

Another possibility is skipping encoding:

```
with open(get_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Comment: I don't know what your code does but my part for sure writes an utf-8 file...
I will add a snippet just for that so you can test it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I see this error : ```newdata = self.stream.read() io.UnsupportedOperation: read```

Comment: @dawhry I think I've provided the right answer for your encoding question...
If you have other issues I am afraid you will have to ask a separate question for that.
Please don't forget to upvote and/or choose my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: this solution almost started to work when I remove 'utf-8' from ```soup.prettify()``` and also I need to change file mode to 'r+'. Now it's appending new values because with 'w' it's truncate whole file content and safe empty file. So the problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

As it's mentioned in the error log, you are writing in byte mode which means the data is already encoded, so you basically need to save the bytes into file. You either encode before writing into file or write file the encoded bytes.

You already encoded the html by using `soup.prettify('utf-8')`. That means no need to pass `encoding` argument to `open` function like:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><header></header></html>")
with open("test.html", "wb") as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify('utf-8'))
```

This should work for you:

```py
 def replace_urls(self):
        find_string_1 = '/blog/'
        find_string_2 = '/contakt/'
        replace_string_1 = 'blog.html'
        replace_string_2 = 'contact.html'

        exclude_dirs = ['media', 'static']

        for (root_path, dirs, files) in os.walk(f'{settings.BASE_DIR}/static/'):
            dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude_dirs]
            for file in files:
                get_file = os.path.join(root_path, file)
                with open(get_file, 'wb') as f:
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml", from_encoding="utf-8")
                    blog_text = soup.find('a', attrs={'href':find_string_1})
                    contact_text = soup.find('a', attrs={'href':find_string_2})
                    blog_text.attrs['href'] = replace_string_1
                    contact_text.attrs['href'] = replace_string_2
                    f.write(soup.prettify('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I tried this solution and now  the problem is: ```markup = markup.read() io.UnsupportedOperation: read```

Comment: I don't see any variable called `markup`, it's not a related issue to that part of the code.

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like issue with BeautifulSoup: ```soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml", from_encoding="utf-8")
  File "C:\...\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 244, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I'm using this function as django command ?

Comment: You should open [another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) if you have more questions.